# How to change facebook comment box if params change in current component (angular6)

Tags: angular, facebook, angular6, facebook-comments

in current i use facebook comments plugin it can show comment only first params if i router to current component (but send new params)

comment box it's not update

> My Question: Is it possible, if i router to current component but
>   change params (http://localhost:4000/content?contentId=1 to
>   http://localhost:4000/content?contentId=2) than ( commentBox Id=1 will
>   change to commentBox Id=2 )

sorry for my english,
thank for your help

> ** i try to use angular2+lazyload , angular6+universal , ngx-facebook but it not work!! ( or i have a mistake ?)

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach you want:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        // do something with the query params
    });

    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
        this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id);
    });
}
```

See https://kamranahmed.info/blog/2018/02/28/dealing-with-route-params-in-angular-5/